# MySQL replication - Error connecting to master

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I'm trying to set up replication in MySQL but I am being given an error that I do not know how to fix -

> ERROR 1218 (08S01): Error connecting to master: Host 'sh047.mydomain.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

I've added the following code to the master my.ini -

```
server-id=238429
log-bin=mysql-bin
log-error=mysql-bin.err
binlog_do_db=my_databases_to_replicate {not literal, have listed the correct databases}
```

And I've added this to the slave my.ini -

```
server-id=2
master-host=192.168.1.15
master-user=replication
master-password=my_password
master-connect-retry=60
replicate-do-db=my_databases_to_replicate
```

The user 'replication' exists and the password that I use in the slave my.ini is correct. Any suggestions as to how to fix this would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all:

> Host 'sh047.mydomain.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL
>   server

Make sure the user `replication` is configurated as `replication@sh047.mydomain.com` (or, but only for testing purposes: `replication@%`) on your master database.

If this doesn't work out, check the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html) for this, there might be one or two special cases (Linux compilation etc.), where that error might occur, too.

Comment: Always the simple answers! I'd added 'replication'@'localhost' only, didn't even think to look there! Thanks.

Comment: Np, you're welcome. I had a similar issue this week, that was why it was still fresh in my memory!

Comment: I think about what happen when DNS service fall down or became slow. I prefer disable DNS reverse lookup (in my.cnf) and use static IP address for replication.